# Why does Mongoid's "presence" validation enable autosave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid, autosave

I had a hard time debugging this one and I was about to ask for help. But I've managed to identify the cause and would like to share my findings in case someone else is running into the same problem. [And maybe someone can  explain *why* it works the way it does]

#### Setup

Let's say I have two Mongoid-Documents, `Customer` and `Order` with a 1:n relation. In addition, `Customer` has an `after_save` callback to synchronize document changes with an external API:

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :orders
  after_save do
    puts "synchronizing customer" # <- not my actual code
  end
end

class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :customer
  validates_presence_of :customer
end
```

Everything works as expected. Creating and updating customers results in the `after_save` callback being triggered and creating orders does not.

#### Change

After a while, `Customer` needs a new field with a default value:

```
class Customer
  # ...
  field :premium, type: Boolean, default: false
end
```

#### Problem

But all of a sudden, things get weird. After this change, creating (or updating) orders result in the customer being saved as well! (I noticed this because of my logs – the synchronization was running for no apparent reason)

```
c = Customer.last
c.orders.create
synchronizing customer  # <- what the?
#=> #<Order _id: 575a995aab265d730b8bddba ...>
```

Strangely, this only happens for existing customers and it only occurs once.

#### Cause

A long and tedious debugging session revealed that the `Order`'s `belongs_to` relation has an `autosave` flag:

```
Order.relations['customer'].autosave?
#=> true
```

It was enabled by the presence validation and in fact, Mongoid's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-relations/#autosaving) notes it casually:

> Note that autosave functionality will automatically be added to a relation when using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or validating presence of the relation.

But `autosave` only saves a document if it was changed, so where did the change come from? Apparently, my new `premium` field with the default value introduced a subtle change:

```
c = Customer.first # a customer from before the change without "premium" attribute
c.changed?
#=> true
c.changes
#=> {"premium"=>[nil, false]}
```

#### Solution

After all, the fix was quite trivial. I just had to explicitly disable autosave on my `belongs_to` relation:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :customer, autosave: false
  validates_presence_of :customer
end
```

#### Open Questions

But the question remains: Why does Mongoid's "presence" validation enable autosave? How could this be the desired default behavior? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this auto-enabling of autosave has been added to Mongoid 3.0 **on purpose so that its behavior is consistent with ActiveRecord**. Have a look at these two issues:

- [validates_presence_of association should enable autosave](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-1676)
- [Behavior of :autosave not consistent with ActiveRecord](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-1680)

The second issue links to an [ActiveRecord doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) which indeed seems to behave the same way, let's particularly quote the following statement:

> Note that `autosave: false` is not same as not declaring `:autosave`. When the `:autosave` option is not present then new association records are saved but the updated association records are not saved.

Here is a [link to the source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/7199e4eee458b8b6777babcb02fc0f01b501d50c/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb#L141) of the Mongoid feature itself.

Also, from all these sources it turns out that you solution was perfect and you indeed should **specifically state `:autosave => false` to disable this feature**.